# Improve the result of EfficientNet

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, overfitting-underfitting, efficientnet

Halo there, I'm still struggling in python.
Now I'm going to use the EfficientNet model to detect the ripeness of palm oil.
I'm using 5852 training picture which is divided into 4 class (1463 per class) with 132 testing picture (33 per class).
After testing with 200 epoch, the result is far from good.
Is there any solution for me to improve the result?
Here's the result of my model accuracy and model loss.

[image: model accuracy]
[image: model loss]

Here's my code

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18AtIP7aOycHPDR84PuQ7iS8aYUdclZIe?usp=sharing

your help means a lot to me.

Answer (score 2):

You have rescaling in your generators, and it may be the root of the problem.

Tensorflow implementation of Efficientnets already contain rescaling layer, so you mustn't rescale images in your ImageDataGenerator. You can check this via .summary() method.

Official documentation says:

> Note: each Keras Application expects a specific kind of input preprocessing. For EfficientNet, input preprocessing is included as part of the model (as a Rescaling layer), and thus tf.keras.applications.efficientnet.preprocess_input is actually a pass-through function. EfficientNet models expect their inputs to be float tensors of pixels with values in the [0-255] range

Resnets, for example, don't have this layer, and you should rescale images before feeding them to the model. It's tricky to remember those things for every single network from tf.keras.applications, so I suggest to just check them before using new models.